# Работа Python с файлами на компьютере

Tags: python

С использованием каких инструментов я могу кодом на Python записывать данные в файлы, находящиеся на диске С, и загружать их в облачные хранилища, наподобие Яндекс.Диска?

Comment: Можете использовать для загрузки на Яндекс библиотеку - selenium, а для работы с файлами смотря какие

Comment: Яндекс диск загружается по webdav

Comment: Если я.диск установлен на компе то можно даже просто скопировать в папку. А записывать `f = open("C:\\myfile.txt", "w");f.write("Привет!");f.close();` Может потребоваться запуск от админа.